# What are the origins of "tech" as an abbreviation for "technology?

Tags: etymology, word-usage, internet, technology

I'm trying to trace the origins and rise in popularity of the abbreviation "tech" from "technology." From what I can tell, the term began taking off in popular culture around the early to mid-1980s, but I'm wondering where it started to appear first and how and why it became so ubiquitous from then to now. Any help appreciated.

I've consulted [Tom Chatfield's book "Netymology,"](https://tomchatfield.net/portfolio/netymology/) which traces the origins of many tech-related terms, but doesn't include "tech" specifically. I can see from this [Collins Dictionary usage graph](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/tech) that the word "tech" started to rise in popularity in the early to mid-1980s. [Google's Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tech&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=15&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) also seems to confirm this timeline. I've also consulted some articles in the NYTs and New Yorker by Steve Lohr and Ben Yagoda about the origins and rise of popular technology-related phrases and words, but they focused on tracing words like "hacker" and "Big Data." I'm specifically interested in why, how, and where "tech" began to rise, in the context of being related to the Internet, software, hardware, etc. It's been suggested that it might have come out of science fiction circles around the 1960s/70s, but I'm trying to run this down.

What I'm really driving at is: I can tell with some clarity from Google's Ngram and date-restricted searches when "tech" as an abbreviation for technology began its rise, but I can't tell the *how*, *where*, or *why* of that rise. I'm new to etymological research so was wondering if any of you could point me in the right direction as far as the right tools to use to figure these questions out.

Comment: What research have you done? We expect you to do your own research and report what you find in your question so we don't all repeat your research. Case Western's college rag was called *Case Tech* in 1903. Cal Tech may have beat them to it, but some of the references are a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Tech has a lot of different meanings. The OED says for a Technical College etc is the oldest, late 19th century. But that's maybe not the same as tech for technology?

Comment: MIT wins. *The Tech* was founded in 1881.

Comment: When I was growing up "tech" usually meant "technical school/college", though it might mean "technician". I was aware of the expression "hi-tech" before I was aware of the use of "tech" to mean just "technology".

Answer (score 1):

Tech Toons cartoon - Colorado Transcript newspaper, July 23, 1967

[image]

Comment: Thanks Phil and Stuart. Phil - I've consulted Tom Chatfield's book "Netymology," which traces the origins of many tech-related terms, but doesn't include "tech" specifically. I can see from this Collins graph that the word "tech" started to rise in popularity in the early to mid-1980s. Thanks for the cartoon - it's interesting to see the word in that context as early as the 60s. I've also consulted some articles in the NYTs and New Yorker by Steve Lohr and Ben Yagoda, but they focused on tracing words like   "hacker" and "Big Data." I'm specifically interested in why/how "tech" began to rise.

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/tech

Comment: See also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramblin'_Wreck_from_Georgia_Tech The song forst appeared in print in 1908.

Comment: Why would this be closed, except for some rigidity about doing research? It was asked only 5 hours ago.

Comment: In this cartoon "tech" would be short for "technician" rather than "technology".

Comment: Yes, I'm really looking for the origins of "tech" asn an abbreviation for "technology;" that likely wasn't very clear in my original post.

Comment: It's not short for anything. Here it is a collective noun like kit or luggage. It's less conceptual than technology. The stuff depicted in the cartoons is tech - like this [box of tech](https://www.itechdeals.com/products/itechdeals-surprise-box-of-tech-limited-quantities-available). That's why I chose to post that particular example - because of that usage.

Comment: No, "tech" is definitely an abbreviation for "technology" in some contexts, and that's the sense in which I'm interested in the etymology. Interestingly, some of its earliest appearances in Google date-restricted searches are in old Scientology newsletters.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the question in two ways: first, when did the abbreviation *Tech* emerge related to technological institutes like Georgia Tech, Virginia Tech, and Texas Tech; when did *tech* emerge as a common noun abbreviation of technology?

### Proper Noun Abbreviation of Tech in University Names

The abbreviation of proper nouns with *Technology* in their title may serve as a precursor for abbreviating *tech* generally. The [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/tech_n1?tab=meaning_and_use#19086845) traces the proper abbreviation back to 1881, when *The Tech* was the title of MIT's (Massachusetts Institute of Technology) newspaper. By 1908, [Georgia Tech's yearbook the *Blueprint*](http://hdl.handle.net/1853/12285) usually prints the school name as the *Georgia School of Technology* (today it's the *Georgia Institute of Technology*) but also uses *Tech* or *the Tech* several times to describe the school, e.g.:

> Ladies and gentlemen, we are now nearing that institution of learning commonly known as **Tech**. (p. 161)

This usage continued throughout the 20th century to refer to many different schools.

### Common Noun Abbreviation of Tech as *Technology*

First, it is worth noting that through the 20th century *tech* also abbreviated other terms: *technician* (from [1953](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/tech_n2?tab=meaning_and_use#19087285)) or *technical* ([1942](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/tech_adj?tab=meaning_and_use#19087468)), for instance. But we are interested in usages that specifically mean *technology*. The [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/tech_n4?tab=meaning_and_use#19087345) traces this usage back to 1982, in a header for the *Times*, 6 May:

> Whitehall backs new **tech** firms.

But searches indicate the abbreviation may have been used before this. For instance, a January 1971 issue of *Landscape Architecture Magazine* ([via JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44665215?searchText=%22high-tech%22&searchUri=%2Faction%2FdoBasicSearch%3FQuery%3D%2522high-tech%2522%26so%3Dold%26pagemark%3DeyJwYWdlIjo2LCJzdGFydHMiOnsiSlNUT1JCYXNpYyI6MTE2fX0%253D%26groupefq%3DWyJyZXZpZXciLCJzZWFyY2hfY2hhcHRlciIsImNvbnRyaWJ1dGVkX3ZpZGVvIiwic2VhcmNoX2FydGljbGUiLCJjb250cmlidXRlZF9hdWRpbyIsImNvbnRyaWJ1dGVkX3RleHQiLCJtcF9yZXNlYXJjaF9yZXBvcnRfcGFydCIsInJlc2VhcmNoX3JlcG9ydCJd&ab_segments=0%2Fbasic_phrase_search%2Fcontrol&refreqid=fastly-default%3A371c5d9e6527c225667899c78e84a3b6&seq=1)) has a review of Lawrence Halprin's book *The RSVP Cycles - Creative Processes in the Human Environment* that mentions "high-tech":

> If in our **high-tech** society, books are able to retain their function as change agents, *The RSVP Cycles* will claim attention.

Then the February 1973 issue of *The Realist* ([JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/community.28043533?searchText=%22high-tech%22&searchUri=%2Faction%2FdoBasicSearch%3FQuery%3D%2522high-tech%2522%26so%3Dold%26pagemark%3DeyJwYWdlIjo4LCJzdGFydHMiOnsiSlNUT1JCYXNpYyI6MTY2fX0%253D%26groupefq%3DWyJyZXNlYXJjaF9yZXBvcnQiLCJzZWFyY2hfYXJ0aWNsZSIsInJldmlldyIsImNvbnRyaWJ1dGVkX2F1ZGlvIiwiY29udHJpYnV0ZWRfdmlkZW8iLCJzZWFyY2hfY2hhcHRlciIsIm1wX3Jlc2VhcmNoX3JlcG9ydF9wYXJ0IiwiY29udHJpYnV0ZWRfdGV4dCJd&ab_segments=0%2Fbasic_phrase_search%2Fcontrol&refreqid=fastly-default%3Ab7099915fbd35b6bbb97573dece6d999&seq=8)) includes an anecdote that invokes the "high tech of guns" white settlers brought to indigenous peoples as an aid in hunting (an inaccurate trope, as indigenous tribes already knew how to hunt, but here it is):

> When I threatened famines, she reassured us that mankind's inventiveness had always saved him from hunger in the past - as when white settlers came to America with the **high tech** of guns and showed the starving Indians how to hunt.

So there is evidence that *tech* referring to technology was being used in the 1970s, so it wasn't coming from nowhere when tech firms rose up in the 1980s.

Answer (score 0):

I've attached the cover page from the September 1956 edition of Popular Electronics. It shows the usage of the word "tech".

[image]

Comment: Do you have some evidence that this is the origin of the term?

Comment: No, but it does show that the term was popular with electronic enthusiasts in the 50's.

Comment: What does the article itself say? I'd like to be sure they really meant "technology" and not "technical" or "technician" or some other "tech". (The OED does say those other two were in use in the 50s.)